# Can I generate Bitmap from R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I try to get bitmap to generate from the `R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round`

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
```

Why did it just return `null`?

Comment: What is `R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round` exactly?? a PNG or a `adaptive-icon` file ?

Comment: It's PNG. Not SVG (XML). It's the default provided by Android when one create a new project

Comment: In this case there should be a xml file in `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder with same name .. just rename it for a while and then try. it should return a valid bitmap ..